# Access livewire component property inside javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm trying to get the value of a property from a livewire component with below script. See below. Any suggestion how to make it work ?

```
<x-order>
    <script>
        console.log($wire.get('order'));
    </script>
</x-order>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
console.log('{!!$product!!}')
```

You can access your properties the same way you would do in a blade file.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use the double or triple curly brackets from Blade:

```
<x-order>
 <script>
    console.log('{{$order}}');
 </script>
</x-order>
```

Assuming you have a **public** property called $order on your Class

If `$order` is an object you need to use the `@json` directive

```
<x-order>
 <script>
    console.log('@json($order)');
 </script>
</x-order>
```